# How can I get redux state in a next 13 server component?

Tags: redux, next.js, state, redux-toolkit

I'm new to next13 and I am having a hard time trying to figure out how can I retrieve redux state in a server component such as my main `page.js` file. Can someone tell me the steps of getting that data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access Redux state in a server component by importing your store and directly calling `store.getState()`. The caveat being the server won't have access to state created/stored on the client, which will be the case if your state was initially set on the client (i.e. via `useDispatch()`).

From my limited testing I've found that you need to set the state from a server component with `store.dispatch(action(payload))`. If you need to make this dispatch from a client component, you can use a [server action](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions) like so:

server component:

```
export default async function PageName() {

  async function setStateFromServer(action, payload) {
    // this is the server action
    'use server';
    store.dispatch(action(payload));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ClientComponent stateSetter={setStateFromServer}/>
    </>
  )
```

client component:

```
'use client';
export const ClientComponent = ({ stateSetter }) => {

  const handleSetState = () => {
    stateSetter(someAction, somePayload)
  }

  return ...
}
```

Then finally, you can access your state:

```
export default async function SomeServerComponent () {
  const state = store.getState();
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. I'm getting: Error: Client Functions cannot be passed directly to Server Functions. Only Functions passed from the Server can be passed back again.

Comment: thats what i am getting as well

Comment: Did you find solution for this, please?

Comment: Pass the state to client-component and then call `dispatch` and set your state in client-component, if you need to access client-side data from server=component e.g. an Id, set it to the path and access it as a path prop from server-component.